# Chrome and javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, parameters, reserved

I am using a Javascript function named top in all pages to set up a standardized heading (on almost 2000 sub-pages). But this is not working in Chrome. It claims (in Console) that

1. top has already been defined (where I try to define the function with two parameters)
2. that property 'top' of object `[object Windows]` is not a function (where I use it)

so it seems that Chrome does not distinguish between an object property without parameters and a user defined function with two parameters

This is accepted in IE, Firefox, Opera, Safari

Comment: So don't name it `top`…

Answer (score 3):

`top` is a [predefined property of the window-object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.top). This is the case in every browser, but the others are so tolerant to let you overwrite it, while chrome doesn't.

The easiest & cleanest thing would be to just rename your property.

Here is a list of words for you, which you should avoid:

[Reserved Words](http://javascript.about.com/library/blreserved.htm)
[Classes and Objects](http://javascript.about.com/library/blclassobj.htm)
[global Properties & Methods](http://javascript.about.com/library/blglobal.htm)

Comment: As I wrote, I have 2000 subpages with this. I am not changing everything just to allow a few users to use Google Chrome.

Comment: @user1600517 erm, you should take a look at the [browser distribution](http://gs.statcounter.com/) and after that think again... If you want to serve a broken page to half of your users ... go for it. Ever heard of bulk search&replace? It's a simple regex and done in less then a minute. And why on earth are you duplicating your javascript instead of putting it into a script where you could fix it in a matter of seconds?

Comment: Of course I am not duplicating the Javascript! The function top(p1,p2) is defined in a module that is included in the pages. But this top-function is then called in every one of the pages with the actual parameters. How do I fix that so easily? This code has been working for 10 years!

Comment: Why should a function (defined and called with parameters) not be able to have the same name as a property that is defined and used without parameters? No confusion is possible. I think the Chrome interpretation is too strict.

Comment: @user since the call is pretty much generic you should be able to replace it with a fairly easy s&r. THis however depends on your document structure. Having code working for a long time and suddenly see it break is something an IT-guy should be used to.

Comment: @user no, the chrome interpretation is good. It prevents forgery. Imagine someone altering the property `document` your script relies on to be the native browser-document. Also it's your (companie's) fault to define a variable in the global scope where it will most likely come to naming collisions. Define your own namespace for such things and you will be save.

Answer (score 1):

If you type:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.top).writable;
```

in the Chrome web developer console, you will see that `window.top` is not writable, at least in chrome it isn’t. And it shouldn’t be either – just use another name or place it inside your own namespace.

Answer (score 0):

try to create a new context for your application/javascript so it wont collide

```
(function(realTop,realWindow) {
   function top() {
      // do something
   }

   // calls our top function
   top();

   realTop.
})(top, window);
```

where realTop is refference to original top object
and realWindow is refference to original window object
inside exampled context

but in my opinion try to avoid names like this in the future

Comment: I am not sure how this could work. Where would you put that code?

Comment: I am not sure how this could work. Where would you put that code?<br>My top-function has two parameters, that should actually be enough for the interpreter to distinguish between a property and a user defined function (overwriting definition like in C++)<br>If I can put something in the Javascript-module (...js) then I am interested. If I have to change 2000 pages, forget it.

Comment: if you will provide me more details about your actual implementation eg. places from which are top method called, i can give you more accurate example

Comment: ok, first the javascript-module  javasc.js:  function top(p1, p2) {  ...  }  function xx(..)

Comment: now the pages:  <html>  <head>  <title>...</title><link rel='stylesheet'...>  <script language='Javascript' src=javasc.js></script>  </head>  <body>  <script language='Javascript'>  top(actp1, actp2);  </script>  ....

Comment: Why should a function (defined and called with parameters) not be able to have the same name as a property that is defined and used without parameters? No confusion is possible. I think the Chrome interpretation is too strict.

Answer (score 0):

you should rename the function to something else less common like "topHeader" or "theHeader"
or something like that. simple names like "top" are sure to be very common.

as a rule of thumb: you should make your variables and functions as unique as possible to reduce the likelihood of naming conflicts.

you can also reduce the chance of a naming conflict by using object literals:

```
var myApp = {
     top:function(){
       //excite some code...
   },
      someOtherProp:function(){}
}

myApp.top();
```